# Wordpress cart and checkout pages loading over a minute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce website. Today I found that when I add (a) product(s) to the Cart it takes over a minute to load the page. Same with the Checkout page. I believe this is not Woocommerce issue because when I remove `[woocommerce_cart]` from Cart page or `[woocommerce_checkout]` from Checkout page (meaning that I load blank pages) it still takes over 60 sec to load. Other pages are loading fairly quickly and there has not been any plugin or theme update/change lately. I have tried disabling all plugins one-by-one. I think it might have to do with serving the dynamic content as other pages are cached by Cloudflare (have also tried disabling Cloudflare and so on). Here is [link to my site](https://nutikell.com) (if you click on some product image and then press the blue button "Lisa korvi" meaning "Add to Cart" then you will see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLY8u.png). I have some experience with troubleshooting but I am still rookie so any help would be really welcome.

Comment: Use Web Developer->Network (Firefox) or a similar tool (depends on the browser) to see which file(s) are taking a long time to load.

Comment: Thank you @manassehkatz for the quick reply. I added an image of Firefox Network tool to the problem description. [link](http://imgur.com/a/ZTRX2) as you can see it is the html js document that is taking over 60 sec to load.

Comment: [link](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170621_0W_1GZ8/1/details/#step1_request2) to the webpagetest.org waterfall shows that time to first byte is 61.378s

Comment: Looks like it is something buried in the Wordpress or Woocommerce code. Hard to guess without seeing the code for the /korv/ page.